# WebSphere Application Server: EJB Modules and JMS Routers

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jms, websphere-6.1

Can an EAR have single EJB Module, single Web Module but have different JMS Router Modules?

I guess the idea is to have each JMS Router Module listen on separate listener ports and hand over message to EJB for processing!

Does this work?

PS: I know the question is little vague, but I am not sure what other details I need to provide. Will update question once I get some comments/feeeback!

Thank You!

Comment: JMS Router is a websphere exclusive term.  I would consult their documentation, and add the websphere tag to this message (websphere-6.1 is probably too particular)

Comment: @John, I don't think  JMS Router is a WebSphere exclusive term. Atleast for WAS there is nothing that WebSphere defines as a JMS Router component.

Comment: @John, I stand corrected. There is this concept of router modules for a Web Service enabled EJB modules.